# Manipular y formatear fecha como String en Javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular

Estoy intentando formatear una fecha que recibo desde mi APIen el siguiente formato: "20200130 14:35:12" y necesito que se vea de la siguiente manera: "2020-01-30 14:35:12". El problema es que no puedo manejar esa fecha como date, debo manejarla como string y hacer los cortes correspondientes para poder darle el formato deseado.
Estoy trabajando con Nodejs, Express, y para el front Angular 8. 
He creado una pipe para este requerimiento la cual dejo abajo.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'procesadorFecha'
})

export class ProcesadorFechaPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(procesador_fecha: string): string{


    let dateString = procesador_fecha;
    let fecha_formateada = '';


    for(let i = 0; i < dateString.length; i++){

       fecha_formateada += dateString[i].split(' ');
    }

    return fecha_formateada;
  }

}
```

Cómo puedo acceder a la posición correspondiente y hacer el split? Entiendo que debería ser algo mas o menos dateString[5].split('-'); 
Pero esto no me ha funcionado, agradezco vuestra ayuda. 
Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    export class ProcesadorFechaPipe implements PipeTransform {

      transform(procesador_fecha: string): string{


      let dateString = procesador_fecha;

      //extraer año,dia y resto de fecha usando substring()
      let año = dateString.substring(0,4);
      let dia = dateString.substr(4,2);
      let restoDeFecha = dateString.substring(6,dateString.length);

      //retornar nueva cadena con guiones
      return año + '-' + dia + '-' + restoDeFecha;

      }

    }
```